# System.in.read is causing loop to execute thrice

Tags: java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class doSwitch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        char choice;

        do {
            System.out.println("Welcome User");
            System.out.println("1. Change plan");
            System.out.println("2. Pay Bill");
            System.out.println("3. Complaints");
            System.out.println("4. De-activate account");
            System.out.println("Choose one the above option");


            choice = (char) System.in.read();


        } while (choice < '1' || choice > '4');

        System.out.println("User's Choice:" + choice);

        ///////////////////////////// switch
        ///////////////////////////// case////////////////////////////////////

        switch (choice) {

        case '1':
            System.out.println("There are different plans than you can opt for");
            break;
        case '2':
            System.out.println("Pay bill using credit card or debit card");
            break;
        case '3':
            System.out.println("In case of complaint call 121");
            break;
        case '4':
            System.out.println("Are you sure you want to discontinue with us");
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

This codes works properly if i entered values between 1 to 4. But If the value is greater than 4 then its executing the loop 3 times. I figured out its taking the value \n, \r. What i m not getting is how can i avoid it. and why it works for values 1-4

Answer (score 3):

try

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

 int choice = sc.nextInt();
```

System.in.read() reads a single byte. In your case it reads the actual inputed character. If the character doesn't equal 1-4, then the loop continues and the next byte will be read, which will be a return character. The scanner objects takes care of this for you.